# Search an element using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

How to check that a `div` element with an `id` has a `p` element with a certain class or not using pure JavaScript nor JQuery.

I am using this code:

```html
   <div id="div">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Full Name">
    </div>
```

```
x = document.getElementById("div").getElementsByTagName("p").length;
```

But it checks for all the `p` elements, I want length of `p` elements with specific a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use
`x = document.getElementById("Id_of_div").getElementsByClassName("class_name").length;`.

class_name is class of p elements.

Comment: did u replace Id_of_div with whatever is you are giving

Answer (score 1):

Updated from updated question:

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll("#div p.form-control").length;
```

or this also works, to be fully spelled out:

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll("div#div p[name='name'].form-control").length;
```

Comment: Sir i have added the html, actually i want to add an error message below the input element using a p tag and for that i want the length of the p tags with the error class.

Comment: Also in the solution that you have given that "div" is id or it is the tag name.